# jQuery UI dialog slower in new version

Tags: performance, jquery-ui-dialog

I was preparing to update our jQuery UI library to the new version when I discovered that it is significantly slower than the one we are using currently at opening dialogs. Opening the same dialog takes ~2 seconds longer than it used to (roughly 1.5s -> 3.5s). We're updating from 1.7.2 to 1.8.11. Has anyone experienced or heard of similar? Any clues as to why this may be happening?

Comment: All browsers or just IE?

Comment: All browsers... (damn character count)